# Gmail autoreply script- one email per day

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, gmail

I am using this script from https://memberfix.rocks/gmail-office-hours/ to send an auto-reply to people who send me emails outside of work hours. It works well, but I would like to know how to modify it so that people who have already received the automated message that day don't keep receiving it. I've read that it involves using Properties Service but I'm not sure exactly how to set it up with the script I have. I don't really have any knowledge of JavaScript so I'd appreciate your help! Thank you.

```
function autoReply() {
    var interval = 5; // if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
    var wkend = [6,0]; // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
    var wkendMessage = "Hi, Thank you for your email. I will get back to you during the school week. Have a great weekend!\n"

var wkdayMessage = "Hi! Thank you for your email.  I will get back to you during school hours.\n"
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if (wkend.indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 5 && hour >= 15 && minute >=30)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(wkendMessage);
    }
  }
  else if (hour < 7 || hour >= 15 && minute >=30) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(wkdayMessage);
    }
  }
}
function doGet() {
 return ContentService.createTextOutput("");
}
```

Comment: You can use apps script to set and unset the native autoreply on gmail. I wrote [this](https://github.com/RemcoE33/apps-script-codebase/blob/main/scripts/OutOfOffice.js) code for it. Follow the steps.

Comment: Thank you. How would I change the dates and time in the script? Also, do I just set a time trigger to run every 5 minutes as I did with my current script?

Comment: No you set two triggers one for the activation and one for the deacttivation. So Two daily triggers.